# Created NSURL is null

Tags: iphone, nsurl

`NSURL` printing `null`. What's the reason?

```
NSString *webStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[webArray objectAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"urlString = %@",webStr); // its printing correct url string

NSURL *webURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:webStr];

NSLog(@"url = %@",webURL); // its printing null

[webURL release];

[webStr release];
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question by clicking the {} button. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should do the following.

```
NSString *webStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[webArray objectAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"urlString = %@",webStr); // its printing correct url string

NSURL *webURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[webStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"url = %@",webURL); // it should print it

[webURL release];

[webStr release];
```

I have used NSASCIIStringEncoding but you can use UTF8 too or any other encoding.

Comment: Ya now only i came to know that the value contains space which is in array..thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, the space is the first thing which is not ok in the url. :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

from the docs for `-[NSURL initWithString:]`:

> If the string was malformed, returns nil.
>
> This method expects URLString to contain any necessary percent escape codes, which are ‘:’, ‘/’, ‘%’, ‘#’, ‘;’, and ‘@’. Note that ‘%’ escapes are translated via UTF-8.

which raises: what's your input?

Comment: Second that. The code Nishanth.jeeva posted does not contain obvious errors and should work as expected.

Comment: [webArray objectAtIndex:1] contains "http://www.chennaispider.com/resources/2838-Details-Chennai-City-Fire-Stations.aspx"...But still url printing null.

Comment: Your URL must meet the requirements specified in RFC 1738: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt — e.g. `http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>`

Comment: @Nishanth.jeeva yup, see Alex Reynold's comment. instead of the input you use, the url you provided should be formed `@"http://www.chennaispider.com/resources/2838-Details-Chennai-City-Fire-Stations.aspx"`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"urlString = %@",webStr); // its printing correct url string
```

It's not printing the correct URL string. It's just printing the string.
So if  NSURL *webURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:webStr]  returns nil it means that your string is not valid URL.