# NSURL set to `nil` instead of path

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have the following code:

```
NSURL* saveToURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.recording filePath]];
NSLog([saveToURL absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"?");
NSLog([self.recording filePath]);
```

which outputs the following

```
2013-08-07 15:51:32.182 SpyApp[49799:c07] ?
2013-08-07 15:51:32.183 SpyApp[49799:c07] /Users/Mike/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/C9EDE058-5C8B-4B75-8638-D5A4265B348F/Documents/Recordings/ujaxvehvjlgwfuw
```

In the debugger, I can also see that `saveToURL` is `nil`, despite the fact that `[self.recording filePath]` returns `/Users/Mike/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/C9EDE058-5C8B-4B75-8638-D5A4265B348F/Documents/Recordings/ujaxvehvjlgwfuw`

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905843/nsurl-is-null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because filePath is a path, not a URL. To create a file URL, use a different method:

```
NSURL* saveToURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self.recording filePath]];
```

On a side note, the first parameter to NSLog should always be a constant string, you never know when filePath could have a `%` in it.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [saveToURL absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"?");
NSLog(@"%@", [self.recording filePath]);
```

Comment: Now it's not set to nil, but the first `NSLog` replaces the space in `Application Support` with a paragraph or so of Simplified Chinese characters

Comment: Here's a sample: `p华扁潳畬整剕L华剕L⨪‪椭楮䙴牯敒摡湩坧瑩䑨瑡㩡渠汩愠杲浵湥t⨪‪敭潭祲愠汬捯瑡潩⁮慦汩摥⨀⨪⬠乛啓慮捲楨敶⁲湵牡档癩佥橢捥坴瑩䑨瑡㩡㩝攠瑸慲搠瑡⁡楤捳牡敤d啎䱌昀畯摮渠汵⁬汣獡s⨪‪华湕牡档癩牥›湩潣獮獩整据⁹敢睴敥⁮牷瑩整⁮湡⁤敲摡搠瑡⁡潦⁲扯敪瑣┠p⨪‪`

Comment: @MikeG Did you also make the changes to `NSLog` as I mentioned in the second part?